# document.log(): "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I know, I know, is a common error and you should look at others and blah blah blah. I have and I could not have found a solution.

This is my ENTIRE code.

```
<div id="div"></div>

<script>
function item(id, price, name, icon){
    this.id = id;
    this.initPrice = 0;
    this.price = price;
    this.name = name;
    this.icon = icon;

    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += this.name + " = $" + price + " <input id=\"itemNum" + this.id + "\" onchange=\"item" + this.id + ".calc()\" type=\"number\" style=\"width: 40px;\" value=\"1\"></input><br>";

    this.calc = function(){
        document.log("yay");
    }
}

var item1 = new item(1, 700, "Barrel #1", "");
item1.calc();
</script>
```

I get the error at line 14 and when I change the input I get the same error at line 14 again. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Only if you don't mark one of those guys the accepted as the accepted answer.  Plus you'll get two rep points yourself!

Comment: There, am I mentally healed now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
console.log("yay");
```

instead of:

```
document.log("yay");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/APFPx/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try `console.log()` and not `document.log()`